# In C language is *p=vec[n] the same as p=&vec[n]?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm self-studying pointers in C, and my question is: is `*p=vec[n]` the same as writing `p=&vec[n]`, where `n` is just an index and `p` is a pointer?

Comment: No, it isn’t the same.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a rough graphical explanation in addition to other answers.

[image: Answer illustration]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words

Answer (score 3):

They are two distinct expressions:

A pointer is a type which holds the address of a piece of memory. So when you write:

```
p = &vec[n]
```

The pointer will have the same address as the address of the `n`th element of `vec`

When you write

```
*p = vec[n]
```

You actually state that the memory which is located at the address of `p` should have the same content as the `n`the element of `vec`.

The following might make it clear:

```
      | original        | p = &vec[n]     | *p = vec[n]
------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------
data  | Address Content | Address Content | Address Content
------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------
p     | 0x12345 0000000 | 0xabcde 0000005 | 0x12345 0000005
vec[n]| 0xabcde 0000005 | 0xabcde 0000005 | 0xabcde 0000005
```

Answer (score 2):

No it's not.

When you do `*p = ...` you assign a value to where `p` is currently pointing.

With `p = ...` you make `p` point somewhere else.